# Ejecutar programa y serie de instrucciones en windows

Tags: sql, windows

Que tal mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo una Base de datos la cual necesito que se migre a diario a otra base ya que en la primera se siguen agregando nuevos registros, la segunda base de datos que es a donde llega la informacion migrada se usa para alimentar un sistema hecho en laravel, la pregunta es: necesito que esta migracion se realice automaticamente a diario para lo cual tengo un programa que me ayuda ya que la primer base esta en foxpro y la otra en sql server, es necesario este programa para mantener la integridad de los datos, busque y encontre que se puede hacer con un .bat pero no encuentro la forma de decirle que vaya ejecutando cada una de las instrucciones.

Ej: abre FoxProToMsSql, da clic en conectar, cambia de pestaña y da clic en conectar, selecciona tablas, da clic en siguiente, ejecuta consulta, migrar datos.

Comment: Tu pregunta es poco clara.. podrias editarla y agregar mas informacion? asi como esta, no sabria que contestarte...

Comment: Se puede usar un .bat, siempre que el programa acepte parametros por la linea de comandos.. que no creo que sea el caso. a menos que puedas generar algun tipo de tarea predefinida y luego ejecutarla por fuera.

Comment: @gbianchi conoces alguna manera de hacer lo que puse en la pregunta, o seria muy complicado, no necesariamente con .bat

Comment: no conozco ese programa. no se si se puede automatizar...

Comment: Dices que ya tienes un programa que se encarga de mantenerte la integridad de las 2 bases? Que programa es? Como funciona, o sea, tiene una interfaz a la que accedes y allí manipulas ventanas, botones y todo eso? Si es así, eso no lo puedes hacer con un programa de línea de comandos como un bat, pero si existen varios programas que puedes usar para hacer esto en automático, el mismo visualfox y sql server te pueden servir, solo que en ambos casos tu mismo.

Comment: Lo tienes que programar, si lo haces en fox, sería un ejecutable que realiza la lectura de la base 1 y 2 para detectar las diferencias (una consulta sql) y después escribe el resultado en la base destino, ese exe si lo puedes programar para que se ejecute a cada cierto tiempo, y no posee interfaz gráfica. Lo otro es, desde sql sever, programar un job, y que a través de un Linked server (con los drivers necesarios para conectar a foxpro), vaya a traer periódicamente la data que necesites (también elabora la consulta sql necesaria). Espero de alumbre tu problema.